# Using a Navigation Controller, Page View Controller, and a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I've fairly new to Swift and I've been reading a lot of answers to questions but I'm still struggling to figure this out. For what I'm building, I want the option to swipe between three main pages but I also want a tab bar that serves as an index and another option to navigate between the three pages. Currently I have three main pages that are each embedded in individual navigation views which are embedded in a page view controller. I tried simply adding a tab bar for each of the pages but that doesn't seem very practical. I was reading on orders of embedding but it doesn't seem to be what I want. How would I go about doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a lot of hierarchy but maybe you can try this

Have a single UIViewController that holds your page view controller. Build a custom uiview guy that holds three buttons which will serve as your tab bar and pin it to the bottom of this UIViewController.

For your page view controller, you can proceed as normal and have it hold 3 
 children. You'll need proper delegation with protocols from: custom tab bar > uiviewcontroller to tell him to move the pages around.